# mocha/chai how to test that a method is called inside a then or catch callback

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocha.js, enzyme, chai

Im trying to test something like this:

```js
// component.js
import React from 'react';
import AsyncModule from '../some/async/module';
import { doSomething } from '../myModule';

.
.
.

const onSubmit = () => {
  const opts = {/* some config */};

  AsyncModule(opts).someAsyncCall().then(resolved => {
    doSomething();
  }).catch(e => {
    // also
    doSomething();
  });
}

class MyCompontent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <Formik onSubmit={onSubmit} ... />;
  }

}
```

I need to test that `doSomething` is being called. So far, I have some tests written, and i've tried some things but none have worked. I need your help with this:

```js
.
.
.
  it.only('should doSomething on Formik submit when AsyncModule.someAsyncCall promise resolves', () => {
    spyDoSomething = spy(myModule, 'doSomething');
    const expectedResponse = {};
    const stubSomeAsyncCall = stub(AsyncModule, 'someAsyncCall');
    stubSomeAsyncCall.resolves(expectedResponse);
    wrapper = mount(<MyCompontent />);
    const formik = wrapper.find('Formik');

    formik.simulate('submit');

    return expect(spyDoSomething).to.has.been.called;
  });
```

this test obviously doesn't pass. How can I check that `doSomething` is being called in the body of the `then` and `catch` callbacks?

Im running node 9.1.0, mocha, chai, enzyme and sinon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jest

```
import AsyncModule from '../some/async/module';
import { doSomething } from '../myModule';

jest.mock('../myModule');
jest.mock('../some/async/module', () => ({
  someAsyncCall: jest.fn()
}));

it('should doSomething on Formik submit when AsyncModule.someAsyncCall promise resolves', () => {
    const expectedResponse = {};

    AsyncModule.stubSomeAsyncCall.mockReturnValue(expectedResponse);
    wrapper = mount(<MyCompontent />);
    const formik = wrapper.find('Formik');

    formik.simulate('submit');

    expect(doSomething).to.has.been.called;
  });
```

Using [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire)

```
it('should doSomething on Formik submit when AsyncModule.someAsyncCall promise resolves', () => {
    const expectedResponse = {};
    const spyDoSomething = sinon.spy();

    proxyquire('../myModule', {
      doSomething: spyDoSomething
    });
    proxyquire('../some/async/module', {
      someAsyncCall: sinon.stub().returns(expectedResponse)
    });


    wrapper = mount(<MyCompontent />);
    const formik = wrapper.find('Formik');

    formik.simulate('submit');

    return expect(spyDoSomething).to.has.been.called;
  });
```

Comment: Hi, I cant use `jest` because, as specified, the host project runs mocha/chai... does this `proxyquire` library can be used with mocha / chai? i'll give it a try... thanks!